# Java - while loop with try-catch causes program to appear not to do anything

Tags: java

When i run the following code, it clears the console but does not appear to do anything.

```
int x = 0; //exception catching loop
while (x == 0);

            ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Scanner Scores = new Scanner(System.in);//creates a scanner for the golfer's last 5 scores
            System.out.println("Please enter the scores from your last five rounds of eighteen-hole golf, in order."); 
            try
            { 
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                System.out.println("Please enter one score.");
                int scorecard = Scores.nextInt();
                values.add(scorecard); 
                }

        }catch(InputMismatchException ex){

            System.out.println("There has been an error. Please enter your last five scores again."); 
            x = 1; //if successful, will allow for continuation of the program. 
        }
```

However, when I take out the while loop and try-catch lines, the program runs fine, I am just unsure of how to do this segment properly.  It shows no errors, but it fails to run.  The part that is bothering me is the fact that i cannot seem to properly code the exception catching system.  (I am a newbie in Java.)

Answer (score 2):

```
while (x == 0);
```

This will run the empty statement infinitely as `x` never changes in the loop.  Unless you want an infinite loop here, remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop:

```
while (x == 0);
```

is an infinitive loop that never ends. If you want it to do anything sensible you should use remove the colon after while and include all code below while loop in brackets `{}`.